# Using static_cast vs implicitly convert from int to double for LHS operand of multiplication

Tags: c++, casting

In our private codebase, I usually see calculations like this:

```
void compute(double scale, int64_t val, int64_t offset) {
  double x;
  x = (static_cast<float>(val) - offset) * scale;
}
```

I'm wondering what is the point of the `static_cast` in this case? `scale` is a double so the result of `val - offset` will be implicitly converted to a `double` prior to multiplication.

Comment: You’re right that this cast seems pointless.

Comment: Unless `int64_` is some exotic user-defined type, i don't see the point either.

Comment: I suppose theoretically `int64_t - int64_t` could produce a value outside the range of `int64_t` (when the first value is very negative and the second is very positive, or vice-versa), where `float` would be *imprecise*, but at least it wouldn't wrap around and become *inaccurate*? If precision isn't super-important, being close enough might be fine if it guarantees it's not involving undefined/implementation-defined behavior (can't recall what signed integer overflow qualifies as off-hand).

Comment: @ShadowRanger — I was just thinking about the same thing. But casting to `double` would be a better choice.

Comment: Is the cast to a `float` or to a `double`?  The wording of your question implies the cast (to double?) is unnecessary because "result of val - offset will be implicitly converted to a double".  Also, the data types `int64_` and `int64_t` should be the same type, along with clarifying what that type actually is?  You may need to modify the question to address these two issues???

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yeah, it doesn't make any sense to voluntarily reduce precision from `double` to `float` here (especially since the follow-up operation is with a `double` , so you'd lose precision on `val` and `offset` and the result of subtracting them, then expand to `double` for the final operation anyway), but in principle it's at least a theoretical benefit. But yeah, no reason to drop to 24 bits of integer precision in a `float` when you could get 53-54 bits of precision with the type you're ultimately working with anyway.

Comment: All of the comments here are assumptions until we get to know what *exactly* type is int64_ and int64_t. Yes, by the name it implies they are integers of 64 bit, but then again we have the cast to float in a double operation so (technically nothing stops me from typedefing a float to int64_t_whatever)... Give the full information so that we can surely tell you that this is just sloppiness by the original author :)